# Codeigniter SQL Query - DATE_ADD

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i'm using CodeIgniter (http://codeigniter.com/) and have a problem with an query:

```
select *
from mb_login_attempts
where ip_adress_hash = ?
and DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) > NOW()
```

i would like to use the following syntax:

```
$this->db->where('ip_adress_hash', $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->ip_address()));
$this->db->where('DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) >','NOW()',TRUE);

if($this->db->count_all_results('mb_login_attempts') >= 3) {

 return true;    

}
```

If i use this code:

```
$sql = "select *
from mb_login_attempts
where ip_adress_hash = ?
and DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) > NOW()";

$val = $this->db->query($sql,$this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->ip_address()));

if($val->num_rows() >= 3) {

 return true;    

}
```

Does anyone have an idea how i get the first code get working correct?
Edit: i have change some code to the comments - but it still doesn't work ...

regards ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the last line with the <strike>`TRUE`</strike> `FALSE` value so it won't escape the `NOW()` function:

```
$this->db->where('DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) >','NOW()', FALSE);
```

EDIT:
Run this query:

```
$this->db->where('ip_adress_hash', $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->ip_address()));
$this->db->where('DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) >','NOW()', FALSE);
$val = $this->db->get('mb_login_attempts');
```

EDIT2:
It Is still okay to use this form:

...

```
$this->db->where('ip_adress_hash', $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->ip_address()));
$this->db->where('DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) >','NOW()', FALSE);

if($this->db->count_all_results('mb_login_attempts') >= 3) {

 return true;    

}
```

Comment: well if i change tHe line to the code above and use "if($this->db->count_all_results('mb_login_attempts') >= 3) { ..." it still does't work ?!

Comment: Please edit your post and add the `count_all_results` line. In addition, `count_all_results` is not equal to `select *` like in your other queries. It is equal to `COUNT (*)`

Comment: please add the code `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` after the line `if($this->db->count_all_results('mb_login_attempts') >= 3)` and post here the result.

Comment: string(...) "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM (`mb_login_attempts`) WHERE `ip_adress_hash` = 'e80a1a342e3540ef0e1...' AND DATE_ADD(attempt_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) > 'NOW()'" ... the hash is edited

Comment: I have edited my post. Please run the new query. I have made a mistake: add FALSE instead of TRUE.